# Mappik hei in word in Onkelos Devarim 23:11?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, targumin

The Artscroll Chumash has no mappik hei in the word "mikrei" in the phrase "mikrei leilya" in Devarim 23:11 in Onkelos.  However, I have seen some non-Artscroll Chumashim that have the mappik hei in the same word.   Which is correct?

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/u/u0523.htm